# invoking Cloud Functions locally through the Firebase CLI?

Tags: node.js, firebase, request, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

I'm trying to follow the steps [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator) to deploy firebase locally.

While I can get the deploy happening and I get the local function URLs I can call I can't invoke the functions via the CLI with Firestore data using the Firebase CLI.

The doc sends me to the example of request in npm but I'm not sure what this means, if I have a cloud function like foo() I can't just type in 'foo()' into my terminal to get that function invoked which looks like what the documentation is implying?

I've run Firebase experimental:functions:shell. I try to call 'addMessage()' but I get an error

> error: (node:19408) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled
>   promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: Cannot encode type
>   ([object Undefined]) to a Firestore Value error: (node:19408)
>   [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are
>   deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled
>   will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

my 'addMessage' function is very simple:

```
// src/add-message/index.ts
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions'

export const listener = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    admin.firestore().collection('messages').add({original: original});
    res.send("hello from firebase!");
})
```

Comment: You're saying that in the shell you're trying to invoke addMessage(), but your function you show is called "listener".  That won't work.  Also, if you have an HTTPS type function it's easier to emulate with `firebase serve --only functions`.

Comment: Also, your functions should wait for async work to complete.  The call to add() is async, but you're not using its returned promise to wait for that work to complete.